# multiple UITableViewCells in multiple UITableViews

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a few UITableViews each with (rather complex) custom cells. Some of those custom cells are the same however. An example will make things clear

tableView1 has customCell1, customCell2
tableView2 has customCell3, customCell2
tableView3 has customCell1, customCell3
...

I can create classes for those customCells inheriting from UITableViewCell. I can control-drag the labels/imageviews from customCell1 from tableview1 to that class to create the outlets. But how do I create a customCell1 in tableView3 and connect the outlets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your best option is to extract your cells in separate xibs, load xibs inside `viewDidLoad()` and register them for each `UITableView`.

So, after extracting cells, connect outlets for each class to the particular cells, and then use the following:

```
var nib1  = UINib(nibName: "customCell1", bundle:nil)
tableView1.registerNib(nib1, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell1")
```

and so on, for each cell and each tableView.

After that you can simply dequeue these cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Here, you can set the values for each UI element and reuse them on every tableView you need.

Comment: Never used xib files/nibs. Works like a charm and was easy peasy to setup with your sample code. Thanks a lot