# I want to create custom table view separator with UIlabel lying between two table view cells, like the calendar app of the iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

[image]

How do i achieve this?

I tried adding the separator view explictly, but creating a UIView, adding a label on it, like this, in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**, where i add the views

```
 UIView *timeLabelPlusSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width+200, 1)];

UILabel *timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cellRect.origin.y -6, 45, 12)];
```

and then adding time label on TimeLabelPlusSeparator as a subview, and back to cell.contentview

what happens here is, that it show on top of the cell, i want it to be in the mid of two cell, like the calendar.

if i do add it on TableView, instead of the cell, than, the cells that were earlier not visible, create a problem,

they show like this

[image]

Can someone point out the problem here.
Yes, **My cells are reused.**

The thing here is, i do want to use the table view only, have to implement the swipe to delete, more, etc also. Creating a different view can take a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Where do you add the views? Cells are reused.

Comment: I doubt that is a tableview. It's more likely to be a Collection view or even a completely custom view.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earlier approach by @nick was partially working,but there was problems that is even in the calendar, as there is some top and bottom margin in the content on the cell.
Because the we are just shifting the separator, but the cell is still there.

What i wanted was to show the button lying on the whole cell.
But could achieve only this ugly thing, since the lower cell always hid the button from the previous cell.
[bottom of button hiding behind lower cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD2ZC.png)

I did try to bring the button in front of all the views, but using
bringSubviewToFront:, taking care of the hierarchy, so it will come on top of table view and appear properly, but even that didn't help.

Ended up using a workaround, by adding a separate UIScrollView for time label, since the table view i used was static.

so i was able to achieve this finally
[Time label in center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRv0p.png)
But now there were two different scrollviews, tableview and the other scrollview.

Made both of them to follow each others' scroll by changing the content offset properly, in the UIScrollView delegate method.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

if([scrollView isEqual:self.timeLabelScrollView]) {
    CGPoint offset = self.firstTableViewWithoutTime.contentOffset;
    offset.y = self.timeLabelScrollView.contentOffset.y;
    [self.firstTableViewWithoutTime setContentOffset:offset];
} else {
    CGPoint offset = self.timeLabelScrollView.contentOffset;
    offset.y = self.firstTableViewWithoutTime.contentOffset.y;
    [self.timeLabelScrollView setContentOffset:offset];
}
```

}

not a very good approach, but works, as i had to manage the tap on the centre of the cell only, so no problem with tapping on timeLabelScrollView not firing didSelectForRowAtIndexPath: method.
Even that can be handled by adding gesture Recogniser if the need arises.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own cell With two UILabels and UIView.

First UILabel if for the time (e.g 08:00).

UIView is for that line you need.

Second UILabel is for the event title.

To create your own custom cell, simply create new class with xib that subclass UITableViewCell. After you do your thing, add it to the UITableView ([multiple UITableViewCells in multiple UITableViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692289/multiple-uitableviewcells-in-multiple-uitableviews/32692559#32692559)).

Comment: Thank you Nick, your solution worked, i was able to create the desired tableview with the cells and label and separator in between as expected.